# pkcs7 padding in .Net vs pkcs5 padding in Java

Tags: java, c#, .net

I have scenario where my existing encryption that is written .Net (C#) is not getting decrypting by Java service (using RSACryptoServiceProvider). The issue identified is that .Net environment support PKCS7 padding but java expecting PkCS5 format.

Can someone please explain me how to make sure .Net RSACryptoServiceProvider encryption with PKCS7 is able to decrypt in Java. Do i need to change my .Net implementation?

Comment: What Java API are you using? Can you provide code how you do encryption/decryption with Java/.NET?

Comment: I am consuming Java web service. I am encrypt message using RSACryptoServiceProvider in C# and Java system trying to decrypt that message from there side

Comment: But what is the API used on the other side? and when you encrypt with .NET, do you use the public key that corresponds to the private key that the other side (java web service) has?

Comment: We used certificate to encrypt. Similar certificate with private key used by java api to decrypt.

Comment: I'm meeting a similar problem. Setting both sides as PKCS7, but they still not understand each other. Do you have any findings so far?